# Why do I get a page without CSS styles?

Tags: theming

Why would the page at admin/people/permissions have very little information and appear like it doesn't have any CSS style applied?

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Because it seems you have an error on this page. If you have enabled Database Logging, look at `admin/reports/dblog` if there are any errors logged when you visit the permissions page.

Comment: It could be that your temp directory isn't set up correctly. Try going to /admin/config/media/file-system and see if your temp directory is set.

Comment: This worked before. Now its not. The tmp dir is set at /tmp... i think thats correct. no error thrown when i go to that page. :(

Comment: Check your console error log, maybe can't load the css file. You could also disable CSS aggregation to test.

Comment: I have disabled the dev themer and all is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have disabled the dev themer and all is better.